# Копирование заранее неизвестного количества строк Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть таблица Google Sheets, которую заполняет пользователь, итоговое количество строк заранее неизвестно. Из нее необходимо перенести отдельные ячейки в другую таблицу с помощью  скрипта. Предполагаю, что можно воспользоваться циклом, в котором вводится переменная - номер строки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать цикл на GAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот неплохая [статья](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) по циклами в JS (они же применяются и в GAS)

Общий смысл, скорее всего в вашем абстрактном случае, это взять всю таблицу через [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()) (по ссылке, кстати, есть и пример цикла, как пройтись по каждой ячейке), и пройтись по каждой ячейке, совершая с ней необходимые действия с нужными вам условиями.

Answer (score 0):

`Sheet.getLastRow()` возвращает последнюю используемую строку на листе.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос. пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой ответ (нажав [edit]) так, чтобы он действительно отвечал на вопрос.